# How to get a hex dump from a binary file into C

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I'm dabbling in a bit of Game Boy save state hacking, and I'm currently getting my head around reading from a binary file in C. I understand that `char` is one byte so I'm reading in chars using the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   char buffer[100];
   int filesize;

   fp = fopen("save file.srm", "r+"); //open
   if(fp == NULL) printf("File loading error number %i\n", errno); 
   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); //seek to end to get file size
   filesize = ftell(fp);
   printf("Filesize is %i bytes\n",filesize);
   
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); //set read point at start of file
   fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, fp);//read into buffer
   
   for(int i=70;i<80;i++) printf("%x\n", buffer[i]); //display
   
   fclose(fp);
   
   return(0);
}
```

The output I get is

```
Filesize is 32768 bytes
ffffff89
66
ffffff85
2
2
ffffff8b
44
ffffff83
c
0
```

I'm trying to load in bytes, so I want each row of the output to have maximum value 0xff. Can someone explain why I'm getting ffffff8b?

Comment: What's this `strlen(buffer)+1`? These aren't strings: use `fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, fp);` or better with the  size and count reversed as `fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp);` and use the value returned to control the next loop.

Comment: I also suggest `printf("%02x\n", buffer[i] & 0xFF);`

Comment: ... or `printf("%02x\n", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);`

Comment: I’m guessing the file size is the same.  You are printing non-deterministic memory.  Size your buffer based off the file size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `if(fp == NULL) printf("File loading error number %i\n", errno);`

When you detect an error, do not just print a message. Either exit the program or do something to correct for the error.

> `char buffer[10];`

Use `unsigned char` for working with raw data. `char` may be signed, which can cause undesired effects.

> `fread(buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 1, fp);`

`buffer` has not been initialized at this point, so the behavior of `strlen(buffer)` is not defined by the C standard. In any case, you do not want to use the length of the string currently in `buffer` as the size for `fread`. You want the size of the array. So use `sizeof buffer` (without the `+1`).

> `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`

Do not iterate to ten. Iterate to the number of bytes put into the buffer by `fread`. `fread` returns `size_t` value that is the number of items read. If you use it as `size_t n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp);`, the number of items (in `n`) will be the number of bytes read, since having `1` for the second argument says each item to read is one byte.

> `printf("%x\n", buffer[i]);`

To print an `unsigned char`, use `%hhx`. Because your `buffer` had signed `char` elements, some of them were negative. When used in this `printf`, they were promoted to negative `int` values. Then, because of the `%x`, `printf` attempted to print them as `unsigned int` values. All the extra bits from the negative values in two’s complement form showed up.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, I edited based on @WeatherVane's comment before I saw your answer to remove the problem with `strlen`, I didn't realise I'd get such fast responses.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply: `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned` by default: that's down to the compiler. In your case, it appears to be `signed`.

When you pass the `char` of `buffer[i]` to `printf()`, it is promoted to `int`, and sign-extended if the original `char` value had its top bit set. Hence anything that's in the range 0x80-0xff gets a lot of `f`s prefixing the value.

If you declare `buffer` to be `unsigned char`, this problem should not occur. But you should, in combination with that, use `"%hhx"` rather than `"%x"` for your `printf()` format, since the `hh` length modifier forces `printf()` to mask the input value so that only those bits applicable to an `unsigned char` (given that you're using the `x` specifier) are used.

Comment: By 'mask the input value' do you mean 'and with 0xFF'?

Comment: @Joe - I do, yes. Sorry if it wasn't clear.